# android eclipse: switch activity briefly shows previous activity screen

Tags: java, android, adk

I am sure this is a basic question, but I'm developing an Android app using ADK and Eclipse.

When I try to transition Activities, the screen goes black and then briefly shows the previous activity screen before "flipping" to the new screen.

I don't have any custom transitions; I'm using the default.

I don't have much going on in my onCreate event (EXCEPT: I load my background image during onCreate!  Could it be this?)

I really am looking at a very snappy transition, like a game like Words with Friends, where it appears to switch "instantly".

Comment: Please would you upload relevant code snippets ?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what phone you're using since different phones use different anamations. Try to call finish(); on every activity but your main one for example.. Or finish them all when the user switches activities